# How to use substring function in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, substring

I am trying to use substring function in postgresql but the error is

> 'No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.'

This is the code

```
select order_id, ship_date,
Substring (ship_date from 5 for 2) as month
from tewt
order by ship_date;
```

Any suggestions regarding this will be helpful.

Comment: why not use date functions to extract the month?

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and explaining the type of `ship_date` would all be helpful.

Comment: When you ask a question on Stackoverflow, add your sample data and explain what you want as result and add your expected result.

Answer (score 0):

If `ship_date` is a date, then don't use string functions.

The right way to extract the month from a date uses `extract()`:

```
select order_id, ship_date,
       extract(month from ship_date) as month
from tewt
order by ship_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it wrong, its a 'String', it wont work for numbers.
thanks to everyone for helping.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c2161b80-ff96-4cac-91f2-21e30db7fcf0/is-there-a-function-like-substring-but-for-integers?forum=transactsql